How to stop Goland (EAP) from removing newline inserted by Ideavim?
GoLand version: GoLand 2024.3 EAP
IdeaVim version: 2.17.0-eap.1
How to replicate: in an open file, just press o (the vim command to insert a newline after the current line, ex. line 10)
What happens: the newline gets very very shortly then it gets removed, and instead goes on insert mode on the next line, ex. line 11.
Expected behavior: the newline should be inserted after the current line (ex. line 10), just how vim works.
Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!
EDIT: Apparently, "EAP" stands for "early access program", some Jetbrains term for beta versions. Dug into why Goland and the plugin were beta versions, realized since I'm using Remote Development which is in beta, beta versions of Goland and IdeaVim spun up.
Works fine when not using Remote Development.

are you sure that the issue isn't related to a compatibility or configuration setting in the EAP (Early Access Program) version?

Please open Settings | Plugins (Host) | Installed tab, and make sure the IdeaVIM plugin is not installed or enabled there.
Also, make sure the IdeaVIM is installed/enabled in Settings | Plugins | Plugins (Client).
Currently, the IdeaVIM doesn't work on the host side when using remote dev.
See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-3334 for details.
